# How can I derived the following? Plane geometry problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

This is from a physics book but is stated without proof. How can I derive the following?

The angles are equal, $a=b=c$.

[image]

I know $a=c$ due to the [Alternate interior angles theorem](https://slideplayer.com/slide/5302217/17/images/4/Theorem+3.1+Alternate+Interior+Angles+Theorem.jpg), but why is $b$ equal to $a$ and $c$?

Comment: extend the vertical line. You have a right angled triangle. One of the angles is $C$ then the other is $90^0 - C$. $B = 90^0 - (90^0 - C) = C$

Answer (score 1):

You know that $90+b+X=180$ so $X=90-b$ and so $c+90+90-b=180$(angles of a triangle ) so $c=b$. Here $X$ is angle $O$ where the three lines intersect .This is under the assumption that the lines used in this proof form 90 degree angles